# Contract functionA call contract functionB ,and functionA can storage value

Tags: function, encode, solidity, abi

I have a problem about handle function value.

likes the title ..

I already know contract's function call other contract's function depend on：

```
addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("function(parameter_type)", parameter ));
```

but what if I want to handle the function's value(ex：bool) temporarily (memory) for condition .

I had seen `abi.encodePacked()` , but I don't even know what parameter feedback to me (compile error , different parameter type), that I can't even storage it .

Some articles write it only for bytes, uint , but I only want to do condition(bool).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that .call unless you want to preserve the msg.sender.

If the msg.sender does not matter for you, I recommend you to look at [interfaces](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/contracts.html#interfaces). Now, what you have to do, is to create an interface with the functionB definition of that you want to call, and then call it.

Example:

(some deployed contract)

```
contract MySecondContract {
  function functionB() public returns(bool) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

(get the deployed contract address and use it in your code like)

```
interface IMySecondContract {
  function functionB() external returns(bool);
}

contract MyFirstContract {
  function functionA() public returns(bool) {
      bool result = IMySecondContract(MySecondContract-address-here).functionB();
      return result;
  }
}
```

If you do want to keep using .call, [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types) you can see that the .call method returns two values.

Something like

```
(bool success, bytes myReturn) = addr.call(...);
```

and then [this](https://www.dhondt.tech/blog/2019/1/Parse-bytes-argument-in-Solidity.html), might work.

Something else that might help is [this new way of debugging](https://medium.com/nomic-labs-blog/better-solidity-debugging-console-log-is-finally-here-fc66c54f2c4a).

Comment: Grateful for your help , your answer is actually my question's point.
I originally thought ```call``` is only way to interact contracts.

Comment: Sorry, May I ask one another question? Is only ```Interface``` can receive boolean , ```Contract``` can't receive?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but I updated the post. See if it helps.